# How to call some method from different variables that from same Object?

Tags: java, methods, javafx

I have some TextField, when user clicks Submit Button my program will send its data to JavaDB. After that, the program will set all TextField to be empty. I am using this code:

```
nama.setText("");
jenis.setText("");
bendera.setText("");
tujuan.setText("");
pelabuhanTerakhir.setText("");
latitude.setText("");
longitude.setText("");
area.setText("");
kecepatan.setText("");
haluan.setText("");
status.setText("");
keterangan.setText("");
waktu.setText(formattedDate_);
```

Is there any way to do that to make my code more efficient in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You could put your TextFields inside a list. Then iterate with the help of an for each loop through this list, and invoke every time on the current entry the method setText("").

Comment: Can you give me the code? I am new in Java. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of TextFields and then go through it with a for loop, each time invoking setText(""). For example:

```
for(int i=0; i<yourTextFieldArray.length; i++) {
    yourTextFieldArray[i].setText("");
}
```